# How to explain to a second year undergrad what quantum computing is?

Tags: quantum-information, education, quantum-computer

I work as a teaching assistant (TA), and I want to explain to my students what is quantum computing and its related fields. I could explain to them what quantum computing means and what research is conducted in this area but it would include many technical terms that they are not aware of yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am a big fan of [this webcomic](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/the-talk-3), which dispels a lot of the pop-science myths about quantum computing